# Move to next UITextField after entering exactly one numeric digit

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I want to make a login screen for customer ID which accepts numeric input with a number pad and moves to next `UITextField` after one number is typed by the user.

I have five `UITextField`, The first `UITextField` should become the first responder with a number pad and should progress through the fields without pressing the return key.  The four `UITextField` are,

```
@IBOutlet weak var customerIdOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var customerIdTwo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var customerIDThree: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var customerIdFive: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var customerIdFour: UITextField!
```

and on pressing the login button, All the values in the `UITextField` should be concatenated.

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
    custID = "\(customerIdOne.text!)\(customerIdTwo.text!)\(customerIDThree.text!)\(customerIdFour.text!)\(customerIdFive.text!)"
    print(custID)
}
```

I am beginner and i want to know if there are efficient ways to implement this.

currently, I used tags with textFieldShouldReturn Delegate method

```
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField.tag == 1
    {
        customerIdOne.resignFirstResponder()
        customerIdTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    if textField.tag == 2
    {
        customerIdTwo.resignFirstResponder()
        customerIDThree.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField.tag == 3
    {
        customerIDThree.resignFirstResponder()
        customerIdFour.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField.tag == 4
    {
        customerIdFour.resignFirstResponder()
        customerIdFive.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField.tag == 5
    {
        customerIdFive.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: use IBOUTLETCOLLECTIONS for your concept

Comment: go with this https://github.com/tkach/PinCodeTextField ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step-1**

create the `IBOutletCollections` and set the **tag** for each textfield for identify which textfield user tapped.

```
@IBOutlet var customerIdButtons: [UITextField]!
```

**Step-2**

create the common extenson for textfield

```
extension yourViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newString = ((textField.text)! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    if newString.count == 1 {
        textFieldShouldReturnSingle(textField, newString : newString)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
func textFieldShouldReturnSingle(_ textField: UITextField, newString : String)
{


    let nextTag: Int = textField.tag + 1
    textField.text = newString
    let nextResponder: UIResponder? = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTag)
    if let nextR = nextResponder
    {
        // Found next responder, so set it.
        nextR.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else
    {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        // call your method
    }
   }

}
```

finally get the all customer ID , then use

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
    var texts:  [String] = []
     customerIdButtons.forEach {  texts.append($0.text!)}
      custID = texts.reduce("", +)
     print(custID)
}
```

Comment: I get a Error in forEach loop. It says ForEach has no member

Comment: @BharathRajKumar - are you created the textfield array for iterate the text values

Comment: Nope. Forgot to create the text Field Array!

Comment: @BharathRajKumar - ha ha ha, plz see the step-1 in my answer

Comment: Facing an issue with the Login Button method. I get only the first number from the first text field. The other numbers aren't getting appended. Sorry if I am troubling you. I am a beginner.

Comment: @BharathRajKumar - are you assign the tag for each text field,

Comment: Yes, I Did. I did set tag 1 to the first Field and so on till Tag 5 to the last text field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EditingChanged` event to see when one text is entered.

[image]

Then you can use `viewWithTag` method to find the next textfield you want to make `FirstResponder`. Here is full code you'll need to write for your purpose.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.viewWithTag(1)?.becomeFirstResponder()
}

@IBAction func editingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if let nextTextField = self.view.viewWithTag(sender.tag + 1) {
        nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

And after that in button action you can get the texts like below:

```
@IBOutlet var customerIDTextFields: [UITextField]!  //IBOutletCollections of all textfields

@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var customerIDString = ""
    self.customerIDTextFields.forEach { (singleCustomerIDTextField) in
        customerIDString.append(singleCustomerIDTextField.text!)
    }
    print(customerIDString)
}
```